# rdo juno openstack glance operations fail

Tags: openstack, centos7

glance operations are failing

*glance --debug image-delete* and *glance --debug image-create* don't spew any errors they just hang indefinitely

```
python-glance-store-0.1.8-1.el7.centos.noarch
python-glanceclient-0.14.1-1.el7.centos.noarch
python-glance-2014.2-1.el7.centos.noarch
openstack-glance-2014.2-1.el7.centos.noarch
```

There are no red flags in /var/log/glance/api.log

There are no red flags in /var/log/glance/registry.log

This is an all-in-one install

Where else should I look?

Specific command I'm running:

```
glance --debug image-create --name 'Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64'\ 
--disk-format qcow2 \
--container-format bare --is-public True \
--file /mnt/ecnas/openstack/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img
```

Comment: What is in your logs?

Comment: glance/api : http://dpaste.com/1S0JYCW glance/registry: http://dpaste.com/20JK3XF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My */var* was only 2G

I re-installed with a 50G */var* and so far I can create an image without problems.